# Compare item versions with Sitecore PowerShell Extension

Tags: powershell-extensions, versions

I'm looking for an option to compare programatically using SPE all the fields of an item that have changed from the latest version x the version prior to that and highlight what changed.
Have anyone done anything like that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found some code from John West some time back and made that into a [module](https://github.com/michaellwest/Sitecore-Visual-Compare) on Github.

You could take the below snippet I converted to PowerShell and make it a report.

```powershell
# Create a list of field names on the Standard Template. This will help us filter out extraneous fields.
$standardTemplate = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID "{1930BBEB-7805-471A-A3BE-4858AC7CF696}"
$standardTemplateTemplateItem = [Sitecore.Data.Items.TemplateItem]$standardTemplate
$standardFields = $standardTemplateTemplateItem.OwnFields + $standardTemplateTemplateItem.Fields | Select-Object -ExpandProperty key -Unique

$itemTemplate = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID "{76036F5E-CBCE-46D1-AF0A-4143F9B557AA}"
$itemTemplateTemplateItem = [Sitecore.Data.Items.TemplateItem]$itemTemplate
$itemTemplateFields = $itemTemplateTemplateItem.OwnFields + $itemTemplateTemplateItem.Fields | Select-Object -ExpandProperty key -Unique

$filterFields = $itemTemplateFields | Where-Object { $standardFields -notcontains $_ } | Sort-Object

$item1 = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID "{110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}" -Version 1
$item2 = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID "{110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}" -Version 2

foreach($filterField in $filterFields) {
    $first = $item1.$filterField
    $second = $item2.$filterField

    if($first -eq $second) {
        Write-Host "$($filterField) : NoChange"
        continue
    }

    $engine = New-Object Sitecore.Text.Diff.DiffEngine
    $source = New-Object Sitecore.Text.Diff.DiffListHtml($first)
    $destination = New-Object Sitecore.Text.Diff.DiffListHtml($second)
    $engine.ProcessDiff($source, $destination, [Sitecore.Text.Diff.DiffEngineLevel]::SlowPerfect) > $null

    foreach($span in $engine.DiffReport()) {
        if($span -and $span.Status -ne "NoChange") {
            Write-Host "$($filterField) : $($span.Status)"
        }
    }
}
```

The `$span.Status` indicates the status of NoChange, Replace, DeleteSource, or AddDestination. I recommend you install the module while you test so you can make sure your report is accurate.

This is where the magic happens in the `FieldDifferenceEvaluator.cs` file. I'm creating html `span`s and injecting the styling.

```csharp
public string GetDifferences(string first, string second)
{
    var engine = new DiffEngine();
    var source = new DiffListHtml(first);
    var destination = new DiffListHtml(second);

    engine.ProcessDiff(source, destination, DiffEngineLevel.SlowPerfect);
    var builder = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (DiffResultSpan span in engine.DiffReport())
    {
        if (span == null) continue;
        switch (span.Status)
        {
            case DiffResultSpanStatus.NoChange:
                Append(builder, first, span.SourceIndex, span.Length);
                break;
            case DiffResultSpanStatus.Replace:
                Append(builder, first, span.SourceIndex, span.Length, "green");
                Append(builder, second, span.DestIndex, span.Length, "red;text-decoration:line-through;font-weight:bold");
                break;
            case DiffResultSpanStatus.DeleteSource:
                Append(builder, first, span.SourceIndex, span.Length, "red;text-decoration:line-through;font-weight:bold");
                break;
            case DiffResultSpanStatus.AddDestination:
                Append(builder, second, span.DestIndex, span.Length, "blue;font-weight:bold");
                break;
        }
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}
```